# Error on overriding magento 2 block with the Plugin(Intercepter)

Tags: magento2, blocks, overrides, plugin, di

I am trying to override a Magento 2 block with the help of di.xml and Plugin(Interceptor). But I am getting an error message

```
[2017-09-27 05:17:33] main.CRITICAL: Packagename\Modulename\Plugin\Block\Export doesn'n extend \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement [] []
```

My di.ml is as below

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\OfflineShipping\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\Export">
        <plugin name="zipcodeExport" type="Packagename\Modulename\Plugin\Block\Export" />
    </type>
</config>
```

and my plugin file code is as below

```
namespace Packagename\Modulename\Plugin\Block;
class Export
    {
      public function beforeGetElementHtml(\Magento\OfflineShipping\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\Export $subject)
      {
           $logger = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface');
           $logger->debug(__METHOD__ . ' -111- ' . __LINE__);

      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try around method and see what happen:

```
namespace Packagename\Modulename\Plugin\Block;


class Export
{

    public function aroundGetElementHtml(
        \Closure $proceed,
            \Magento\OfflineShipping\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\Export $subject

    )
    {
        return $proceed();
    }
}
```